# (IE) Loading external html for knockout template with jquery load function

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, knockout.js

The fiddle below works fine in Chrome and Firefox but not IE 9

http://jsfiddle.net/2HxPp/37/

```
     $('#person-template').load('/echo/html/', {
        html: '<h3 data-bind="text: name"></h3><p>Credits: <span data-bind="text: credits"></span></p>'
    }, function() {
//nothing happens in IE
        ko.applyBindings(vm);
    });
```

How can this issue be fixed? Thanks.

Comment: In which IE? IE6,7,8,9,10? Because in IE10 it seems it works...

Comment: I would try to use one of the many external template frameworks around instead. I have made one with a small footprint. http://www.nuget.org/packages/Knockout.Bootstrap/

Comment: @nemesv sorry for the lack of specifics, it is IE9.